# What does it mean "xvalue has identity"?

Tags: c++, c++11, move-semantics, xvalue

C++11 introduced new value categories, one of them is `xvalue`.

It is [explained](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38169963/8157187) by Stroustrup as something like (`im` category): "it is a value, which has identity, but can be moved from".

Another source,
 [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_category) explains:

> a glvalue is an expression whose evaluation determines the identity of an object, bit-field, or function;

And `xvalue` is a `glvalue`, so this is statement is true for `xvalue` too.

Now, I thought that if an `xvalue` has identity, then I can check if two `xvalue`s refer to the same object, so I take the address of an `xvalue`. As it turned out, it is not allowed:

```
int main() {
    int a;
    int *b = &std::move(a); // NOT ALLOWED
}
```

What does it mean that `xvalue` has identity?

Comment: Are you sure the answer convinces you? See my comment below his answer :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The xvalue does have an identity, but there's a separate rule in the language that a unary `&`-expression requires an lvalue operand. From [expr.unary.op]:

> The result of the unary `&` operator is a pointer to its operand. The operand shall be an lvalue  [...]

You can look at the identity of an xvalue after performing rvalue-to-lvalue conversion by binding the xvalue to a reference:

```
int &&r = std::move(a);
int *p = &r;  // OK
```

Comment: Yes, but you can do the "same" to a prvalue, if you assign it to `const &`. And a prvalue doesn't have an identity.

Comment: @geza: In C++17, you would say that the prvalue is materialized (= converted to a glvalue) when it's bound to a reference. Prior to C++17, binding to a reference s just a general rvalue-to-lvalue conversion, which does indeed *create* a glvalue if a prvalue is given. But in the OP's example there is no prvalue, so the identity we're talking about is always unambiguously the same. ("No materialization happens", in C++17-terms.)

Comment: Another thing to consider is that `std::move` converts any value to a glvalue, but if the original value was already a glvalue, then its glvalueness is unchanged (only "l" is changed to "x").

Comment: @geza: A bit like this: https://sketch.io/render/sk-7b28f85a9409d8a5a0afc955c9b7f667.jpeg

Comment: So basically you say, that because xvalue has identity, it doesn't need materialization (because it is already materialized), while a prvalue needs it in certain situations? That's the main difference between a "has identity" an a 
 "doesn't have identity" variable?

Comment: @geza: Kind of -- but not "variable", but rather "value". A variable can never be a prvalue. Either a variable is an object, or it's a reference, and once a value binds to a reference, it must become a glvalue.