# Do Temporary Objects have identity?

Tags: c++, object, return-value, standards

I've been questioning myself whether **Temporary Objects** do have **identity**. I know that the following is valid:

```
object.temporary_object().modify()
```

as far as the object returned is non-const or the function called on the object do not modify immutable members.

According to [the value categories definition](http://www.stroustrup.com/terminology.pdf), **prvalue**s results can be **moved** but have no identity and as Temporary Objects are result of prvalue expressions, how can they be modified?

Comment: *maybe* related, to understand identity better: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50783525/what-does-it-mean-xvalue-has-identity

Comment: @geza Thanks, that answer helped me understanding better the relation xvalue-identity

Comment: @downvoters can you explain the -1? This question seems perfectly reasonable to me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The linked document is not normative. In some sense it seems to describe what prvalues ought to be, rather than what they were at the time. In C++17, it became true that prvalues have no identity---but in C++11 and C++14, it was not quite so.

In C++11 and C++14, a prvalue of class type *does* have an identity, because, as you've observed, it's possible to call a method on it, and there are also ways to observe its address. Similarly, prvalues of array type have identity. Prvalues of scalar type (*e.g.,* integer literals) do not have identity. Binding them to references will cause the materialization of a temporary object, which now has an address but is no longer observable as a prvalue.

In C++17, prvalues have no identity, and are not temporary objects, but are instead expressions that can be used to create temporary (or non-temporary) objects. Moving from a prvalue to an object effectively "invokes" the prvalue. A temporary object is only observable as an xvalue.

Comment: Tangentally and amusingly to me, you can create a C++ type that behaves somewhat like a prvalue expression does, but can itself be treated as an object separate from what it creates: `template<class F>struct prvalue{ F f; operator std::invoke_result_t<F>()&&{ return f(); } };`

Answer (score 1):

You can modify the temporary object just like any other. The modifications will just be moot as they are thrown away when the life-time of the temporary object ends and it is destructed.

It's kind of similar to something like this:

```
SomeClass object;
// Some code...

{
    // Entering a new scope, the life-time of variables in here ends when the scope ends
    SomeOtherClass temporary_object = object.temporary_object();

    temporary_object.modify();

    // Now the scope ends, and the life-time of temporary_object with it
}

// Here there exists no such things as "temporary_object"
```

All modifications you made to `temporary_objects` will be lost when the nested scope ends, and `temporary_object` is destructed.

---

One important disclaimer: You can design the `SomeOtherClass` (from the above example) to keep a *link* (reference or pointer) to `object`, and the `modify()` function can use that link to modify `object` itself. *Those* modifications will still exist after `temporary_object` is destructed, as they are modification on `object` itself instead of `temporary_object`.