# Can we take the address of xvalue

Tags: c++, c++11, rvalue, xvalue

As I know, there have been come concepts since C++11: lvalue, rvalue, prvalue, xvalue etc.

As my understanding, if a function returns a local variable, it should be a rvalue.

```
std::string func() { return std::string("abc"); }
auto ret = func(); // func returns a rvalue
```

And for xvalue, `std::move(x)` is a kind of xvalue.

I think I'm right.

Today, my colleague told me that we can't get the address of rvalue, so `&func()` is illegal, but we can get the address of xvalue. This is a way to distinguish rvalue and xvalue...

Well, I just tried: `int a = 1; std::cout << &std::move(a);`. But the compiler said:

```
error: taking address of xvalue (rvalue reference)
```

So is my colleague wrong?

**UPDATE**

In fact, my colleague misunderstood the meaning of "has identity" and the unary `&` operator and I'm confused by him...

Here is a very nice question about this issue: [What does it mean "xvalue has identity"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50783525/what-does-it-mean-xvalue-has-identity)

Comment: My own take: theoretically, C++ _could_ have been designed to allow `&` on xvalues. Indeed, we can write `T* get_addr(T&& y) { return &y; }` and then use `get_addr(std::move(x))` so defining `&std::move(x)` in that way looks feasible. However, is it a good idea to take the address of an _expiring_ object? Writing `T* p = get_addr(std::move(x));` creates a dangling pointer (pointless). To avoid that, we could extend the lifetime of the xvalue by binding it to a reference, but at that point we have an lvalue to use `&` on. It looks like allowing `&xvalue()` would only be harmful in most cases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your colleague is incorrect.  C++ has always required an lvalue for use with the address of operator.  This is called out explicitly in [[expr.unary.op]/3](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/expr.unary.op#3):

> The operand of the unary `&` operator shall be an lvalue of some type `T`. The result is a prvalue.

If the standard had used `glvalue` instead of `lvalue` then they would have been correct but per [[fig:basic.lval]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/fig:basic.lval) `lvalue` and `xvalue` are distinct leaves of `glvalue` so `xvalue`s are not allowed.

Comment: Yes you are right. In fact my colleague just misunderstood the meaning of "has identity"... Here is a nice question about it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50783525/what-does-it-mean-xvalue-has-identity